# Authentication popup issue in Firefox using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, firefox, popup

I'm trying to open up a link that looks like this

https://ecms.network.lan/otcs/llisapi.dll?func=ll&objId=120499404&objAction=browse&viewType=1

but the authentication popup keeps showing up asking for credentials

[image: popup message]

I'm using Selenium, Python and after configuring the drive I try to open the link using the following structure:

https://username:password@ecms.network.lan/otcs/llisapi.dll?func=ll&objId=120499404&objAction=browse&viewType=1

but it doesn't work.

I would appreciate any suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert()

alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials("username", "password")

alert.Accept()
```

Answer (score 0):

When a new window pops up you have to handle this in Selenium.

```
    web = webdriver.Firefox()
    web.get('URL OF PAGE')

    # DEFINE MAIN PAGE WINDOW:
    main_page = web.current_window_handle
    

    #SWITCH WINDOW TO NEW POPUP PAGE
    for handle in web.window_handles:
        if handle != main_page:
            popup_page = handle
    web.switch_to.window(popup_page)
```

See: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html

Then you can use Selenium to `send_keys("Username")` and `send_keys("Password")` for example.

As per: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys for your help! Decided to just try switching the drivers, from Firefox to Edge, and it fixed all the problems

Comment: Please don't use new posts for new explanations or information, just add this as an update to your question.